# Flutter DateTime format

Tags: flutter, datetime

I was trying to check if the user input is correct by parsing the input String.
In the following code, 26-10-2 should throw an error cause 2 is not a valid year. However, it seems to be correct. I only want to accept 4 digits that is 2020,2021 etc.

```
  try {
           DateFormat('d-MM-yyyy').parse("26-10-2");
                    
       } catch (e) {

          log("wrong format");

        }
```

I know I can use DateTimePicker but I also want users to let them type in.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more and add some code snippet?

Comment: @VivekChib I have updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm actually also surprised that it accepted that. I also thought that `yyyy` would only match on 4 digit years. In any case, one way to check is to see if the formatted parsed date is the same as the input. So like

```
final dateString = "26-10-2";
final dateformat =  DateFormat('d-MM-yyyy');
final date = dateformat.parse(dateString);
if (dateString == dateformat.format(date)) {
  print('correct');
} else {
  print('incorrect');
}
```

I don't know if there's a better way.

Comment: I think your solution is good enough, except you might have to update to dateformat.format(date).toString() since you are comparing with dateString which is String data type. Thanks man. I will make it an accepted answer

Comment: @WaiYanMinMin `dateformat.format(date)` returns a string

Comment: yea u r correct. my bad